# Using scientific prefixes

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a device that calculates resistances in the range of 10uΩ upto 200KΩ. I want to write a piece of code to convert these numbers into a simpler to read format; e.g: convert 99912.3125 to 99.91KΩ and 0.010039 to 10.04mΩ. so far I have written this code which works ok for the most part:

```
float num[9] = {100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1,  0.1, 0.01, 0.001};
float nums[9] =  {99999.9,9999.9,999.9,99.9,9.9,0.9,0.09,0.009,0.0009};
String prefixes[3] = {"mΩ","Ω","KΩ"};
int powers[3] = {-3,0,3};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int prefix(int x){
  return (x < 0) ? 0 : (x/3)+1;
}

int decimalPlaces(int x){
  return (x < 0) ? abs(x) : 3-(int(x)%3);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
    Serial.print(num[i],6);
    Serial.print("\t");
    if (i>4){
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    int lg = log10(num[i]);
    int pref = prefix(lg);
    Serial.print(" | ");
    Serial.print(num[i]/pow(10,powers[pref]),decimalPlaces(lg));
    Serial.println(prefixes[pref]);
  }
  Serial.println("##############################");
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
    Serial.print(nums[i],6);
    Serial.print("\t");
    if (i>3){
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    int lg = log10(nums[i]);
    int pref = prefix(lg);
    Serial.print(" | ");
    Serial.print(nums[i]/pow(10,powers[pref]),decimalPlaces(lg));
    Serial.println(prefixes[pref]);
  }
  Serial.println("##############################");
  Serial.println(int(log10(0.1)));
  Serial.println(int(log10(0.9)));
  Serial.println(int(log10(1)));
  while(true);
}
```

And here is the output of the code:

[image]

but there is an issue with changing between milli ohm and the ohm range. As you can see log10(0.9) is the same as log10(1), despite being on the same order of magnitude as 0.1! so instead of 0.9 being displayed as 900mΩ, it is displayed as 0.900Ω which is not what I intended to do. Is there an easier way to achieve this type of formatting? if not how can I solve the issue for this small bug?

Comment: Instead of `log10(num[i])`, have you tried `floor(log10(num[i]))`?

Comment: @Amadeus Initially I tried it with floor like this: `floor(int(log10(num[i])))` and it didn't work, but it seems if I do floor before int it works fine and it's fixed now! Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that `int(log10(0.9))` is zero, while `int(log(0.09))` is `-2`

Comment: Isn't that rather a text processing question and thus the math `log10` function a suboptimal approach?

Comment: `floor` is the correct way to round _down_, casting to `int` rounds to zero. But you will still have problems eventually because negative powers of 10 are not exactly representable in IEEE floats, so they might be mathematically too large or too small and thereby give `log10` values that round the wrong way.

Comment: @datafiddler we are formatting the numbers here, what could be more efficient than mathematically getting them to the correct range?

Comment: OK, you're transforming a string to a float and print that with a variable number of decimal digits. But using `log10` just to count digits is an abuse like using `pow(2, n)` instead of shifting. And you deserve the related problems. ( IMHO )